How does Common Lisp represent control modifiers for character keys?
According to CLTL2, all of functions that deal with key modifiers seem to be removed from the standard. SBCL does not seem to have any of those.
What is the printing representation of characters with modifiers, and how do I specify them in character notation, if there is such a notation in Common Lisp?
In other words, does Common Lisp have a notation to read characters and sequences of characters with modifiers similar to what they do in Emacs: ?\C-q (Ctrl-q) or ?\M-\S-o (Alt-Shift-o).
Is it advisable to implement something as those functions that are deleted from the standard, if I would to implement my own, or is there something in wider use? As a side question: is it known why are those functions removed from the standard?

Your first sentence answers the question. From https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node25.html "X3J13 voted in March 1989 (CHARACTER-PROPOSAL)   to replace the notion of bits and font attributes with that of implementation-defined attributes."

Why removed? Probably because it imposed a high cost on every implementation to support a very narrow and specific notion of character attributes as a font and keyboard modifier bits. That's fine for elisp but no one else wants to take up space for those attributes in every string. And consider modern CLs that support unicode--which has the good sense not to mix up the notions of characters and fonts.

See also https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node135.html "A character repertoire defines a collection of characters independent of their specific rendered image or font". It's clear from this page that X3J13 was looking at emerging ISO standards regarding characters. This was a couple of years before unicode arrived on the scene.

Thanks. I saw all the pages related to characters, but I didn't really understand everything they say. I realized by now, I have to implement this myself, just as if I would do it in C. Sometimes, it is a bit confusing when I have to implement some low-level details like this, which I expect to be provided since often, CL offers very high-level features. I don't know why I expected that :). But I have figured it out. Thank you for the further explanation and the link.

Perhaps there's a library somewhere. If not, perhaps you could write one and contribute it.

There are various bits and pieces in different libraries. It was relatively easy to implement my own by just bit-masking characters codes with modifier bits. I have seen some other libraries using lists of characters and modifiers. If I ever finish my hobby project I am working on, I will release it as the part of that project, but I don't have anything that is usable as a standalone library. Currently it is just part of my reader.

Presumably you are talking about the character control-bit functions described here.
The related Issue Writeup in the HyperSpec only says:

Earlier versions of Common LISP incorporated FONT and BITS as attributes of character objects.  These and other supported attributes are considered implementation-defined attributes and if supported by an implementation effect the action of selected functions.

In any case, the Standard does not forbid implementations from doing something like this:

Additional, implementation-defined attributes of characters are also permitted so that, for example, two characters with the same code may differ in some other, implementation-defined way.

There is no standard printed representation for characters with modifiers since Common Lisp implementations aren't required to support these "characters."
It is probably best not to think of them as characters at all, but as keypresses. Ordinarily pressing a key with modifiers is intended to signal something rather than to generate a character. The usual way to handle this is to put the terminal or console into raw mode so that a program isn't waiting for a user to press Enter before it can get the input. This requires interacting with the environment, which you can do from C by manipulating the termios struct in Linux. Here is a tutorial about getting that working.
You can interface with the C code to do this from Lisp. SBCL has some Posix extensions that allow you to manipulate termios structs so that you don't need to go through C. Or you can use a library that does this for you, for example you could use trivial-raw-io or terminal-keypress.

Yes that was the one I meant, sorry for the wrong link. That is unfortunate there is no standard representation. I am familiar with raw/cooked modes, and various ways to get input. Unfortunately, termios is non-portable to certain OS, and neither of those libraries are. I can cook my own, or go via pdcurses at low level, but the issue is how to represent characters with modifiers in the application. This almost requires to use my own character type and to convert back and forth between the implementation character type. Fells a bit cumbersome. Thank you for the input! :) You confirmed my fear.

I was hoping that SBCL supported sb-posix:tcgetattr on Windows with some hackery, but I just checked the source code and it doesn't. As for how to represent characters with modifiers: terminal-keypress uses a CL struct to represent keypresses, with boolean fields for Ctrl and Alt modifiers.

I don't know about cygwin, but I am about 99% sure msys2 does not port tcgetattr. I have used win32 console API already, the low level to read-in and manipulate stdin/out is not the biggest problem. My bigger problem is if I should convert characters to integers and mask myself for controls, or is it better to use a list or defstruct. Either case, seems like I have to do my own character management which involves some overhead, but then I guess I'll use some native event queue anyway. Than, I  am skipping SBCL command loop there. I am still a bit unclear how everything hangs together honestly.
